# Accessing a specific property/column in FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to write a function that when a region is clicked on the map, a dot will show and will highlight the region, and show a property in its `FeatureCollection (UHIAdded)`. Here is my code:

```
lat.setValue('Lat: ' + coords.lat.toFixed(2));
lon.setValue('Lon: ' + coords.lon.toFixed(2));
Dayall.setValue('Annual daytime UHI: ' + ee.Number(UHIAdded.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat)).get('UHIday')));
print(UHIAdded.filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat)).getArray('Area'));
```

The result showed up as this:

Lat: 37.84
Lon: -120.81

> Annual daytime UHI: ee.Number({ "type": "Invocation", "arguments": {
> "object": { "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "collection": {
> "type": "Invocation", "arguments": { "collection": { "type":
> "Invocation", "arguments": { "collection": { "type": "Invocation",
> "arguments": { "tableId":......)

and the printed value is

> Null

Why won't `FeatureCollection.get` work and how do I access the specific property/column

Answer (score 0):

Without all of your code and a working example if will be difficult, but probably something like this:

```
Map.onClick(function(coords) {
    var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
    Map.addLayer(point)
})
```